# How to pick an undergraduate if you know you want to pursue an academic career? (math)

Tags: undergraduate

If you're certain that you want to pursue an academic career, what should you look for in an undergraduate math program? What makes an undergraduate program good for those who want to do a PhD and later conduct research, have a career in the academia? How important or reliable is the prestige a certain institution might have in this regard?

Comment: Math curricula:
 [Middle East Technical University](https://catalog.metu.edu.tr/program.php?fac_prog=236),
 [Hacettepe University](http://akts.hacettepe.edu.tr/ders_listesi.php?prg_ref=PRGRAM_0000000000000000000000281&birim_kod=328&submenuheader=2&prg_kod=328),
 [Ankara University](http://mathematics.science.ankara.edu.tr/wp-content/uploads/sites/356/2020/09/ENG-Matematik-Katalog.pdf),
 [Bilkent University](https://catalog.bilkent.edu.tr/dep/d03.html)

Comment: Math faculty:
 [Middle East Technical University](https://math.metu.edu.tr/en/full-time-faculty),
 [Hacettepe University](http://www.mat.hacettepe.edu.tr/academic_staff.html#1),
 [Ankara University](http://mathematics.science.ankara.edu.tr/en/staff-2/),
 [Bilkent University](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~cvmath/faculty.html)

Comment: Information about FEDEK can be acquired from [here](http://fedek.org.tr/).

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the sort of question we answer here. But the undergraduate institution is probably less important than you think.

Comment: Do you have an idea where I could find an answer to this question @Buffy?

Comment: There are too many variables and _you_ are one of them. Go where you think you will get an appropriate level of academic support. The worldwide reputation means little for this. I went to a very small place (liberal arts - math) and turned out fine.

Comment: Thank you for you advice @Buffy!

Comment: ¨I'll be able to go to Middle East Technical University (METU) or Bilkent University.¨: How?

Comment: [This is an opinion:] Having seen all 4 of the departments, forgot Hacettepe and Ankara uni. they teach in Turkish. METU and Bilkent both have good math departments and give good educations but the student/faculty ratio is an order of magnitude high in METU than in Bilkent. That is a high disadvantage. If you can pay for the education, definitely Bilkent. If you have no problem with money, don't even consider staying in Turkey.

Comment: @Our by studying for 10 months, to be honest. I'm sorry if the statement seems presumptuous, I was just making a guess considering I studied for two months the last time and got pretty close to getting into METU. EDIT: Thank you for your opinion though! Unfortunately, no, I don't have the money to study abroad, and couldn't get a scholarship from the 20+ universities I applied in the United States.